# Import data from one table and loop through another and extract the result using Script task

Tags: sql, ssis, msbi, script-task

I have been asked to do a task which is import data from one table and loop through that data with another table and fetch the matching result using SSIS Script task or script component.

I am very poor in script writing could anyone help me with this please?

**Table 1**

```
username    cust_id
a               2
b               4
c               5
```

**Table 2**

```
cust_id        city 
2              london   
4              bngl
```

Loop through table-1 data with table-2 data and fetch the O/p as following

```
username    cust_id
a               2
b               4
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JOIN

SELECT username, cust_id FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.cust_id = Table2.cust_id

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this in SQL but how can I do this in Script task. How can I establish connection and save the output?